# Can you have an optional parameter in CloudFormation for AWS Specific Parameters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, parameters, aws-cloudformation

How do you include an optional list of AWS specific resources in a CloudFormation template?

For example, an optional list of existing EBS volumes to attach to an EC2 instance?

The parameter would be defined as usual:

```
  AdditionalExistingVolumes:
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Volume::Id>
    Description: Existing AWS volumes to attach to the instance.
```

However when it comes to use it, you only want to include the list if the user provided some values.

With a string parameter you would use a Condition along with the function !If to optional include AWS::NoValue.

How do you do this with a list of AWS types?

Comment: Short answer: No. Duplicated post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40184169/aws-cloudformation-parameter-dependency

Comment: It is not exactly a duplicate because this case is a collection of things, and a collection of things could be zero length. But looks like this is not accepted by CFN anyways and the answer seems to be No, as you said @DavidLin . It is sad because then just defining the List of things would have satisfied the optional feature by nature: It would have been more mathematical to support the empty collection instead of treat it as an special case, as they are doing now.

Comment: I have gotten around this in cases by using `!Not [!Equals [!Join ['', !Ref SomeListParameter '']]`. I have more details [here](https://www.awholenother.com/2020/06/19/optional-comma-delimited-list-parameters-in-cloudformation.html).