# CloudFormation - filter a list of allowed values based on the value of another parameter

Tags: parameters, aws-cloudformation

In CloudFormation, is there a way filter a list of allowed values for a parameter, based on the value of another parameter?

For example, if I had two parameters to allow users to specify a VPC and some subnets, I could use this snippet -

```
Parameters:
  VpcId:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC::Id'
  AllSubnetIds:
    Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
```

However, there is nothing stopping users from selecting one VPC and then choosing subnets from another VPC. What I would like is to have the subnets available for users to select from limited to those in the VPC that has been selected.

Obviously the stack create/update would fail if that was invalid for the underlying resource, but in an ideal world the operation would fail before attempting to create/update the resource.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately not - Parameters are independent from each other.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40184169/aws-cloudformation-parameter-dependency), it has a similar discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had seen that question, but it refers to a different issue and can be solved though the use of `Rules`. Unfortunately that isn't an option for my scenario.